# RxSwift - mapping contentOffset of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I'm trying to apply some logic to a component when a `UITableView` is scrolled, but I can't map the `contentOffset` property to return the `y`'s value.

I'm testing like this but nothing happens:

```
table.rx.contentOffset.map {debugPrint($0)}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Map on its own will do nothing. You need to subscribe to the stream:

```
table.rx.contentOffset.subscribe {
  print("offset now \($0.element)")
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Great. So, I can make this logic inside the callback of subscribe with no problem? I ask that because I'm new to RxSwift and thought that the "right way" to do it was directly mapping and subscribing to a `Variable`. I need to bind the offSet.y to another object's offSet.y if that offSet is higher than 200.

Comment: My understanding is that there are 'hot' and 'cold' observables - see [the RxSwift docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/HotAndColdObservables.md), and that in order for a cold observable to work, there has to be a subscribe call at some point (the map on its own just maps values only *if* the observable is already firing).

Comment: Although looking at the definition of hot vs cold given in the link in my previous comment, you'd think that the content offset property would be a hot observable - but the way the code is behaving suggests strongly that it isn't

Comment: I got it. This worked:

`tableProfissionais.rx.contentOffset.map({$0.y}).bind(to: tableViewOffsetY).disposed(by: disposeBag)`

Thank you!

Comment: Just one important note here, Do not use a `Variable`, it's deprecated. If you're binding to some input you're better off using a `Relay` (or a `Subject`)